# Null Hypothesis Help

Tags: hypothesis-testing

So ive been struggling with the concept of null hypothesis and getting it laid out properly. I have a question for class that deals with it and I was wondering if im on the right path. The question is:

a.  Write the null and alternative hypotheses for a test of whether the marketing campaign was successful.  (I.e., whether the mean revenue with the marketing campaign is higher than the mean revenue before the marketing campaign.)

My answer was 
H0: mean after >= mean before
H1: mean after < mean before

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to CV. Since you’re new here, you may want to take our [tour], which has information for new users. Please add `[self-study]` tag and read its [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Hint: You try to reject the null hypothesis.

Comment: Or is it H0: before mean <= mean after (since this would be no change) and H1: after mean > before mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think of hypotheses testing and the null hypotheses as a *[presumption of innocence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presumption_of_innocence)*. The null hypotheses is *like* the equivalent of *"not guilty until proven otherwise"*. Only when there is enough evidence (data) to reject the null hypotheses one can claim a treatment is effective.

In your example:

One wants to know whether the marketing campaing raises the revenue. The null hypotheses would be "$H_0$: the marketing campaing has no effect". Only when the revenue provides enough evidence you can refute the statement and claim effectiveness of the marketing campaign and reject $H_0$.

Or more symbolic $H_0$: mean after $\leq$ mean before and the alternative hypotheses $H_A$: mean after $>$ mean before

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I kind of realized that a little after. Its kind of the idea of H0 is that nothing will change, H1 is that there is change. So H0 mean<= after mean because we assume the mean wont change?

Comment: Exactly. The test is one sided, which might seem a bit strange. Most null hypotheses are two sided. '$H_0$: treatment has no effect' and $H_A$: treatment has effect. Then the effect size is used to determine if the effect is positive or negative (if there is any).

Comment: What about if it says if something is associated to something? would that require the symbom = and then the alternate would be !=?

Comment: Can you further explain *something is associated to something* ?

Comment: I need to write a Null hypothesis to see if c is associated with ne for example Im assuming that would be H0: c=ne H1: c!=ne

Comment: If $c$ and $ne$ are random variables that doesn't make any sense. You could write $E[C] = E[NE]$ or $\mu_c = \mu_{ne}$  in that case. When testing for correlations take a look at regression.

Comment: They are realted to each other using ne=.4*c-.8 so basically I plugged in c to get ne along with n(which isnt needed in this problem). Its asking me to write a null and alternate hypothesis that the number of ne is associated with c

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to dedicate the problem to a seperate question. Then you could clearly state the problem.